# How do i test advertisement locally with displaying ads?

Tags: angular, web, admob, adsense, ads

I have to test ads locally on my website. I am using Adsense and it is asking the website URL for registering. I don't have a registered domain name. Is it possible to test ads locally? Is there any option available? 
Here is my code,
In index.html,

```html
    <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
    <script>
        (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({
            google_ad_client: "my id that adsense generated",
            enable_page_level_ads: true
        });
    </script>
```

In my homepage.html,

```html
<div>
    <ins class="adsbygoogle" style="display:block" data-ad-client="ca-pub-9687007734660221" data-ad-slot="2930227358" data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
</div>
```

Some people said to add data-adtest for testing ads. But it is not working.

Can anyone help me with this?

Note:
I have a registered website https://www.tilbudsappen.no/#/
But Adsense rejected it because of the following reason,
We've found policy violations on http://www.tilbudsappen.no that are preventing your site from being approved:
Valuable Inventory: No content

As stated in our Program policies, we may not show Google ads on pages or apps with little to no value and/or excessive advertising until changes are made. This includes hosted ad pages or pages or apps without content.

My website is for some small works to do. It is not like blogs which contain some 20 articles in it.
I don't know what content needs to add for my website.
Can you please tell me what needs to do?
Thanks.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Signing up for AdSense without a domain (yet)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40433420/signing-up-for-adsense-without-a-domain-yet)

Comment: @Rafal: Thank you for your reply. I have updated my question now. Can you please check and tell me what I need to do?